# How to set multiple java classpaths in git bash terminal

Tags: java, bash

I have 3 directories named lib, src and out,
and 2 files, `Main.java` in the src folder and `utils.jar` in the lib folder.

To compile the `Main.java` file I ran the following command:

```
$ javac -cp lib/utils.jar -d out src/Main.java
```

But now I can't seem to run it without changing my directory to out and running this command:

```
$ java -cp ../lib/utils.jar:. Main
```

As a side note, running

```
$ java -cp .:../lib/utils.jar Main
```

gives me:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

even though it's the same thing no?

Anyway running this command (or similar variations)

```
$ java -cp lib/utils.jar:out Main
```

gives me

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main  
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

How can I run the Main class without changing the directory to out?

Comment: Using `.` in the class path means _"add the current directory to the class path"_, but your class `Main` (in the default package) is not in the current directory, it is in the `out` directory, so you need to add `./out` to the class path (as in use `java -cp ./out:./lib/utils.jar Main` or `java -cp ./lib/utils.jar:./out Main`). As an aside, using classes in the default package is fraught with all kinds of problems, don't use the default package.

Comment: As to why switching the order doesn't work, I don't know, unless `Main.java` doesn't actually have a `main`-method, and utils.jar also has a `Main.class` and does have `main` method.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Using `java -cp ./out:./lib/utils.jar Main` still gives the same error. However I tried `java -cp lib\utils.jar;out Main` in Windows cmd which worked fine so I'm not sure whats wrong with git bash but I guess I'll use cmd from now on. Thanks though :)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Though I just remembered why I'm using bash in the first place is because I'm trying to both compile and run from a single shell script so not sure how to do that from cmd

Comment: Create a .bat file

Comment: Ah thanks will do that instead